# Java regex exclude dots in file path

Tags: java, regex, string

I've been messing around with regex's for a while now, and I can't seem to get it right.

I've got a text file containing some file information along with paths.  The text I wish to search for is this:

```
Windows\System32\user32.dll
```

The contents of the file is this:

```
Windows\System32\user32.dll
WINDOW~1.000\Windows\System32\user32.dll
Windows.old.000\Windows\System32\user32.dll
```

The pattern I've been using was simply `\\Windows\\System32\\user32.dll` but this is now matching all of the entries.

What I need to do is to exclude any that contain a `.` or `~` character in the first portion of the file path, ignoring the `.` in the actual file name.

I've been trying things like `[^.~]` but I'm probably doing it completely wrong.

Any input or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Don't user regex, use `contains` and other String methods on each line.

Comment: I agree with @MarounMaroun . Don't  regex where `contains()` (or any other string method) can do the job

Comment: Normally I would use contains, but the problem is that all of the lines in the file contain the actual string I'm looking for.  I need to exclude the ones that start incorrectly.  I'll have a play about, thanks.

Comment: You can try `startsWith()` if those are the only three entries. If not you can use `indexOf() == 0` to determine if that string is at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to match exactly `Windows\System32\user32.dll` , your java regex would be:`^Windows\\\\System32\\\\user32[.]dll$`

Note that, you have to escape the backslash twice in java regex, once is for the regex, once for String.

E.g.

- `\\w` in java regex is for `\w`(word character)
- `\\\\w` in java regex is for `\w` (slash and w)`

dot has special meaning in regex too, better escape (`\\.`) or put it in char-class: `[.]`

then, come to your requirement:

> What I need to do is to exclude any that contain a . or ~ character in the first portion of the file path

You could do:

```
^[^.~\\\\]+\\\\.+
```

It matches string:

- first part (before the first backslash) contains no `. or ~`
- after the first `\` it could be anything.

Comment: or use the `lookingAt` or `matches`method.

Comment: Thanks for the information that's done just the job.